# How to update my Nuget package manager in VISUAL STUDIO 2012

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, nuget

[image: Visual studio shows no update button to update the Nuget package manager, but when i try to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer i'm getting a error saying update the nuget manager by going to particular website (https://www.nuget.org/downloads)]

Visual studio shows no update button to update the Nuget package manager, but when i try to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer i'm getting a error saying update the nuget manager by going to particular website (https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

Comment: I downloaded nuget.exe from that webiste, if i open and run that i don't know why it is closing automatically

Comment: nuget.exe is a command line app, not the visual studio extension.

Comment: Yeah, i was suggested to upgrade the nuget package manager by using that cmd terminal by offical docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgradation of VS12 nuget package manager is not possible now!
If you want any packages that is compatible with VS2012, while installing any packages you check with versions of that particular package version in nuget official website (supported for VS12) by clicking on the version tab.

Comment: Yeah, I'm following that now :)

Answer (score 1):

You already have the most recent version of NuGet that is available for Visual Studio 2012. VS2012 is very old (in software terms) and hasn't has feature upgrades in a long time. You'll need to upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio for some NuGet features to work (for example, to be compatible with packages that use features only available in newer versions of NuGet). Alternatively, you might have luck with Entity Framework 6, rather than Entity Framework Core. However, there's a chance that even then you'll need to install an older version of EF6, rather than the newest version, to find a version that is compatible with VS2012.